# How to bind a changing datasource to a set of svg?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to visualize a circle with a random colour at a random x and y coordinate, then add an extra colourful circle at a random location every second.

I am using `d3.timer` to run a function that appends x and y coordinates to my `dataset` object, which is bound to all of the `circle` objects. When I print the `dataset` object, I can see that my function does in fact append the new x and y coordinates to my `dataset` object. However, the visualization does not update with the new circles. How can I add a new circle every second?

Relevant functions below:

```
  var reshuffleData = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log('Reshuffling')
    dataset.push({x: randomXPosition(), y: randomYPosition()})
  }
    console.log(dataset)
    return true
  }

  d3.timer(reshuffleData, 10);
```

Full jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d74Le5xk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't not working because d3.timer is used incorrectly. As d3.timer just takes a function to paint next animation frame. We do not control when the this function will be called but it will be called most likely  (1/ frames per second seconds). Where FPS may change every second.

If you want to do something periodically use **setInterval** also you need to redraw the circles once the dataset size is changed.

Following is the jsfiddle link for the working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/d74Le5xk/3/

Also attaching the code here for reference.

**HTML**

```
<svg class='canvas'></svg>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {

  var width = 420, height = 200;

  var randomXPosition = function(d){
    return Math.random() * width;
  }
  var randomYPosition = function(d){
    return Math.random() * height;
  }

  var dataset = [];
  var circleBatchSize = 5;
  var maxCircleCount = 100;

  for (var i=0; i < circleBatchSize; i++){
    dataset.push({x: randomXPosition(), y: randomYPosition()})
  }

  var testInterval = null;
  var reshuffleData = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<circleBatchSize; i++){

        dataset.push({x: randomXPosition(), y: randomYPosition()})
        //return true;
    }
    console.log('Reshuffled ' + dataset.length)
    console.log(dataset)

    if(dataset.length > maxCircleCount) {
        clearInterval(testInterval);
    }
  }

  console.log(dataset);

  var colours = ['#FDBB30', '#EE3124', '#EC008C', '#F47521', '#7AC143', '#00B0DD'];
  var randomColour = function() {
    return colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
  }
  //d3.timer(reshuffleData, 0, 5000);
  testInterval = window.setInterval(reshuffleData, 2000);

  var canvas = d3.select('.canvas')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .style('background-color', 'black');

  var datasetOldLength = 0;
  function drawCircles() {
    if(datasetOldLength === dataset.length ) {
        return;
    }
    datasetOldLength = dataset.length;
    var circles = canvas.selectAll('circle')
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .style('r', 20)
      .style('fill', randomColour)
      .style('cx', function(d) { return d.x} )
      .style('cy', function(d) { return d.y} );

    if(dataset.length > maxCircleCount) {
        return true;
    }
  }

  d3.timer(drawCircles, 1000);
})();
```

**d3.timer usage explanation**

```
# d3.timer(function[, delay[, time]])
```

**[function]** argument is called at every frame rendering by d3. It's called until it returns true.

optional **[delay]** in milliseconds to delay the first invocation of the [function]. Delay is taken since the [time] passed in third argument. If [time] is not passed delay starts from new Date().getTime().

optional **[time]** is the epoch time from when the delay is considered.

Reference https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#timers